# Fade on mouse out unless mouseover within set time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a solution for the following problem:
Om mouseover a div fades in. On mouseout it fades out again. Simple and this works, but I would like to set a condition that the fadeing Out only happens if mouseover doesn't occur again within a set time, say 2s. Simple delay() does not work since it will then happen anyway... Is there a way to set some kind of timer to cancel a function from running if an event triggers within this time?

Comment: Set a timeout in a variable, on mouseover, cancel the timeout, on mouseout, set the timeout

Comment: Stackoverflow fixes problems, we don't do your projects for you.  See "[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and edit your question.  Thanks.

Comment: Just add `.stop()` http://api.jquery.com/stop/ You need to show a simplified example to demonstrate the issue so people can tell you where you need to add `stop()`. Use http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#foo').hover(function() {
    var $bar = $('#bar');
    clearTimeout($bar.data('fadeOutTimer'));
    $bar.fadeIn();
}, function() {
    var $bar = $('#bar');
    $bar.data('fadeOutTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        $bar.fadeOut();
    }, 3000));
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5oLcfzj1/

Answer (score 1):

Although this is probably really unhelpful, to add contrast to the jQuery answers, I made a pure JavaScript answer....

```
document.getElementById("test").onmouseover = function(){
  this.style.opacity = "1";
  if (typeof exTimeout !== "undefined") clearTimeout(exTimeout);
}

document.getElementById("test").onmouseleave = function(){
  exTimeout = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("test").style.opacity = "0"
  }, 2000);
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/cgykpug5/1/)

(Side note, this only changes opacity so it still takes up physical space on the page, and it also requires CSS3 transitions to be made smooth)

Comment: If you're using CSS transitions, why not also just use the :hover selector and remove the need for JavaScript completely?

Comment: @AlienWebguy  True, I didn't really think of it like that.  Might as well delete my answer.

Comment: @AlienWebguy  Lol, you should post that as another answer, XD

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class=container1></div>
<div class=container2></div>

$('container1').mouseover(function(){
    $('container2').show(500);
});
$('container1').mouseout(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('container2').hide(500);
    }, 2000);
});
```